# Java program for retrieving autosys status

Tags: java, autosys

Please tell me how to retrieve the status of `autosys` command from java program.
we can execute the commands using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` but how to get `autosys` status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the `autosys` commend but if you can execute using the `Runtime` then you need to see the output of execution of command. If autosys will return something upon execution you will get it in out `InputStream` or error in `ErrorStream` in case of error.

Try something like this:

```
public static void printStream(InputStream is, String type){
try
   {
      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
      String line=null;
      while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(type + ">" + line);    
   } catch (IOException ioe){
           ioe.printStackTrace();  
   }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    String cmd = "command to execute";
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    printStream(proc.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");
    printStream(proc.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Process` has a method `exitValue()` to get the exit value for the subprocess. [exitValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue())

Example:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = rt.exec("ls -al");
process.waitFor();
System.out.println(process.exitValue());
```

Comment: please make sure that exitValue is command specific. check your program which exitValue it will return for success or error. Normally 0 for success and non-zero for error. But in case of ls command it will 0.